# Error while importing class in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, import, error-handling

I am getting the error on importing a class located in a subpackage in JSP.

**Effective code of index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page import="a.b.TestDetails" contentType="text/html" 
pageEncoding="UTF-8" errorPage="Error/error-page.jsp"%>
```

**Error i am recieving:**

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

When i remove the `import` page loads correctly but when i use it to import class, it gives me above error.

Comment: just a guess, is it not because it's a test class ? and so not present in your war's WEB-INF/classes

Comment: I dont think classes (which are not servlets) need to be written in web.xml?

Comment: show your stacktraces or the server . Also your `jsp` code .

Answer (score 0):

try :

`<%@ page import="a.b.TestDetails" %>`

**// here a.b is package & sub-package name & TestDetails llbe name of Class which you want to import.**

remove `contentType="text/html"` & other code.

Then test it again, if still problem post me.

Comment: I dont think `contentType="text/html"` is the problem . even works for me if add it. i guess it might be the problem with package and class

Comment: Yes I have also doubt on it that there's problem in package name.

Comment: yup :) . content type doesnt cause the problem , might be with the java class and how he access it here